# Converting first order logic to PNF then evaluating under interpretation

Tags: first-order-logic

> Transform $∀z(P(z) → Q(z)) ∧ ∃zS(z)$ into PNF. Then transform $∀z(P(z) →
> > Q(z)) ∧ ∃zS(z)$ into PNF **without** renaming the variables. Finally, state the result of evaluating your two transformed formulae given a domain consisting of $D=(a,b)$ and interpretation that makes $S(a)$, $Q(a)$ and $Q(b)$ true.

I've transformed to PNF, but have no clue what to do for the second part of the question.

PNF: $∀z∃y(¬P(z) ∨ Q(z)) ∧ S(y))$

PNF without renaming: $∀z∃z((¬P(z) ∨ Q(z)) ∧ S(z))$

Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

> How to evaluate : $∀z∃y \ [¬P(z)∨Q(z))∧S(y)]$ in a domain $D=\{ a, b \}$ with an interpretation that makes $S(a), Q(a)$ and $Q(b)$ *true*.

Consider the outer quantifier : $∀z$ and consider in turn all elements of the domain $D$.

*(i)* When $z$ evalautes to $a$ we have $Q(a)$ true, and thus also $¬P(a)∨Q(a)$ is true. For this value of $z$ we can choose $a$ as value for $y$, and we have that $S(a)$ is true.

In conclusion, when $z$ evalautes to $a$, we have that $∃y \ [¬P(z)∨Q(z))∧S(y)]$ is true.

*(ii)* Now for $b$ as value for $z$. $Q(b)$ is true and again $¬P(b)∨Q(b)$ is. As above, we can choose $a$ as value for $y$, and thus, being $S(a)$ true, we have that also when $z$ evalautes to $b$, $∃y \ [¬P(z)∨Q(z))∧S(y)]$ is true.

Conclusion : for all possible value of $z$ in the domain $D$, $∃y \ [¬P(z)∨Q(z))∧S(y)]$ is true, i.e.

> $∀z∃y \ [¬P(z)∨Q(z))∧S(y)]$

is true in $D$ with the said interpretation.

Comment: Many thanks. So the other formula (which hasn't got renamed variables) will be false since S(b) is not known to be true ?

Comment: @ak1652 - exactly.